# Bootstrap Jumbotron text overflow issue

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid

Text overflows out of jumbotron.
[image]

Followed the sample of jumbotron from the bootstrap documentation, not able to figure out why the formatting cannot fit text within jumbotron.

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid ">
  <div class="container ml-4 mr-3 mb-4">
    <img align='center' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='product_pics/' + product.product_image)}}"  alt="...">
    <h1 >{{ product.title }}</h1>
    <h5>Created by: {{product.author.username}}</h5>
    <h6>Published: {{ product.date.strftime('%B %d, %Y') }}</h6>
    <p class="lead">{{product.text}}</p>
    
    {% if product.author == current_user %}
      <div>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ url_for('products.update', product_id=product.id) }}">Update</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#del_modal">Delete</button>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-wrap` to the `<p>` class.

```
 <p class="lead text-wrap">{{product.text}}</p>
```

Comment: The issue still persists... Where else should I look for the root cause?

Comment: I don't know, in Bootstrap 4 that `text-wrap` applies. Is the dynamic content having an effect? Can't see why but maybe......